# How to add Library 'android-android-25' to LibGdx?

Tags: libgdx, audiorecord, amplitude

I'm trying to use the android's AudioRecord in LibGdx, but when I press on "Add library 'android-android-25' to classpath" nothing happens.
I cannot use LibGdx's AudioRecorder, because I want to get the amplitude of the microphone (like .getMaxAmplitude).

Thanks

Comment: Here is a picture of what it looks like: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4614/kq2895wd_jpg.htm

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AudioRecord class of Android platform because LibGDX is cross platform development library.

but you can use it only for Android platform  using interface and core module of  LibGDX